# Context is resetting in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code in `App.js` (I am using a router):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DefaultSwitch from './components/DefaultSwitch/DefaultSwitch';
import ColorsContext from './contexts/ColorsContext';
import CreatePageContext from './contexts/CreatePageContext';
import './scss/App.scss';

const App = () => {
    const [pageColors, setPageColors] = useState({
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        isLightButtons: false,
        borderColor: '#FF0000',
    });
    console.log('render');

    const [newPageBlocks, setNewPageBlocks] = useState({});

    return (
        <ColorsContext.Provider value={{ pageColors, setPageColors }}>
            <CreatePageContext.Provider 
                value={{ newPageBlocks, setNewPageBlocks }}>
                <DefaultSwitch />
            </CreatePageContext.Provider>
        </ColorsContext.Provider>
    );
};
export default App;
```

I have noticed that as I navigate between links in the router the `newPageBlocks` are resetting to `{}` this is because App.js is being rendered again. I have confirmed this by using a `console.log`. Is this normal? Should the main app component be re-rendering again when I navigate through the router? It makes the context useless because it keeps reseting.

Comment: useState should return the value you passed to "setNewPageBlocks". The only way to lose a state is when unmounting and mounting again. Btw this is nothing to do with contexts

Comment: Should app be mounting and unmounting though?

Comment: Maybe if you render your App conditionally. But if you have a single `ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))`, it shouldn't